# Unable to compile GNU-EFI Program

Tags: c, linux, uefi

I've followed one tutorial to study about UEFI shell
Problem is when I try compile I get this which I don't understand

```
ERROR:`hello.c: In function ‘efi_main’:
hello.c:8:10: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘Print’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    Print(L"Hi,,,");
          ^~~~~~~~
In file included from hello.c:2:0:
/usr/local/include/efi/efilib.h:503:1: note: expected ‘const CHAR16 * {aka const short unsigned int *}’ but argument is of type ‘int *’
 Print (
 ^~~~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
/tmp/ccGlbBgD.o: In function `efi_main':
hello.c:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to `InitializeLib'
hello.c:(.text+0x30): undefined reference to `Print'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`
```

Tutorial URL: "https://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-programming/hello.html"

By the way I'm new to C programming

**EDIT:** I tried gcc version 7.4.0 and 5.5.0 to compile the program plus I installed gnu-efi via "sudo apt-get install gnu-efi" and brought changes to the code from the tutorial
here is the code

```
#include <efi/efi.h>
#include <efi/efilib.h>
EFI_STATUS
EFIAPI
efi_main (EFI_HANDLE ImageHandle, EFI_SYSTEM_TABLE *SystemTable) {
    InitializeLib(ImageHandle, SystemTable);
    Print(L"Hi,,,");
    return EFI_SUCCESS;
}
```

commands I tried

GCC v7.4.0`gcc hello.c -I /usr/include/efi/x86_64`

GCC v5.5.0`gcc-5 hello.c -I /usr/include/efi/x86_64`

Comment: What compiler options are you using? On what architecture are you compiling? `uname -a`? `gcc --version`?

Comment: Please present a [mre] that demonstrates the issue, in the question itself, so that your question is self-contained.  Supposing that you're using code straight from the tutorial you mention, however, the problem, in general terms, is probably that it makes unsafe assumptions that in fact are not satisfied by the C implementation you are using.

Comment: @kamilcuk I used gcc v7.4.0 and v5.5.0 compiler to compile my program

Comment: Well, I get the same error as you do

Comment: It is not a good idea to start learning C form EFI programming. First know C well, then program EFI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error comes because you didn't use the compiler options you should have had while compiling the efi program. The error shown comes from lack of the `-fshort-wchar` option. Undefined references comes from not linking against efi libraries. The `undefined reference to 'main'` comes from not using `-shared` compile options.

The site you linked shows example makefile on how to compile the program. The site also has a short explanation of some compile flags that are used to compile the program. The simplest would be to use that makefile. Follow it to compile the efi program.

Other way is to by hand extract the compile and linker flags from the makefile and use proper compile options to compile.

Comment: I tried using the makefile, it doesn't show the "Print()" error but I get this error, "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
/tmp/ccZIwhS5.o: In function `efi_main':
hello.c:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to `InitializeLib'
hello.c:(.text+0x30): undefined reference to `Print'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status"

Comment: That error is from gcc and flags used in makefile plus I included "CC=gcc" and "$(TARGET): hello.c
 $(CC) hello.c $(CFLAGS)"

Comment: I mean, and? So your line is wrong, you compiled it wrongly, and you got bad results... Remove your line, rename `hello.c` to `main.c` and hit `make`. Please read your link carefully, it says: `f you want to try compiling the program itself, cut-and-paste the preceding lines into a file called __main.c__`, it's really good and well explained. I only have a link error, because `elf_x86_64_efi.lds` on my archlinux is in `/usr/lib/` not in `/usr/lib64/gnuefi/`, that's simple fix of EFI_LDS in makefile.

Answer (score 0):

After some hard research I got the EFI program working, but I didn't use the "Makefile" instead I did it manually

Commands used:

```
gcc main.c -c -fno-stack-protector -fPIC -fshort-wchar -mno-red-zone -I /usr/include/efi -I /usr/include/efi/x86_64 -DEFI_FUNCTION_WRAPPER -o main.o
ld main.o /usr/lib/crt0-efi-x86_64.o -nostdlib -znocombreloc -T /usr/lib/elf_x86_64_efi.lds -shared -Bsymbolic -L /usr/lib -l:libgnuefi.a -l:libefi.a -o main.so
objcopy -j .text -j .sdata -j .data -j .dynamic -j .dynsym -j .rel -j .rela -j .reloc --target=efi-app-x86_64 main.so main.efi
```

Comment: Please don't post images of code. Instead copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Comment: Old but still useful.  `Makefile` for `GNU-EFI` See https://github.com/fpmurphy/UEFI-Utilities/blob/master/helloworld/Makefile